# Put a information box below the input field

Tags: html, css

I want to display extra information when the user typing text in the input field. How can I position the information box directly below the input field? That is something similar to the dynamic result below the input box when searching using google.

Also, is it possible to detect and expand the size of the information box when the text is too long? Thanks.

Comment: can you post the code that you've attempted so far?

Comment: @jnpcl: I am new to css. I have tried using some div block, with the relative and absolute position. However, the display is just messy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an autocomplete type of functionality?

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

Comment: Thanks. Not that I look for. I am looking for a method to position a box below the input for me to write my own validation and other information.